# How to build an F# project via a .fsproj file?

Tags: f#

I have a single F# file which I build so far via

```
fsc --standalone Foo.fs
```

into a single executable file which I can distribute to others who have not installed the F# toolchain.

Now I thought I move to a .fsproj file which scales better the more files I add to my project. Consider the following .fsproj file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="FSharp.NET.Sdk;Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.NET.Sdk" Version="1.0.*" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Core" Version="4.5.*" />
    <Compile Include="Foo.fsx" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

If I run `dotnet build` in a directory which contains both files, then I get the following output:

```
C:\Users\BillGates\.nuget\packages\fsharp.net.sdk\1.0.5\build\FSharp.NET.Core.Sdk.targets(170,9): error MSB6006: "dotnet.exe" exited with code -2147450730. [C:\temp\Foo.fsproj]
```

Searching for the error code `-2147450730` did not help me. Any idea what is wrong with my setup? Any hints how to build a stand alone executable file from a F# file?

I'm using the following .NET versions:

```
dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.401
 Commit:    91b1c13032

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.15063
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.401\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.3
  Commit:  124038c13e

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: I don't know the ins and outs of the .Net Core project system, so I usually rely on a template like https://github.com/TheAngryByrd/MiniScaffold. (Run `dotnet new -i MiniScaffold` followed by `dotnet new mini-scaffold -lang F# -n ProjectName -o path\to\where\you\want\ProjectName`). It sets up an .fsproj file for a library rather than an exe, so it might not be exactly what you're looking for, but searching for other dotnet templates for F# might help.

Comment: Also, error code -2147450730 is `0x80008096` in hex. Googling for `dotnet error code 0x80008096` turned up https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/05/30/asp-net-core-2-1-0-now-available/, where someone mentioned getting that error code when moving to a different .Net Core version. Which version are you running, and have you changed your .Net Core version recently?

Comment: The output of `dotnet --info` shows that I'm using Version 2.1 which should be fine.

Comment: Not sure if this is on purpose but in your fsproj you have specified `Foo.fsx` whereas before you were saying `Foo.fs`

Answer (score 3):

DO not use `FSharp.NET.Sdk` with any recent tooling. It was an intermediate package as long as F# was not in the box. Nowadays F# is in the box and the following should give you a working version:

`dotnet new -lang f#
dotnet build`